# Error: "CUDNN STATUS NOT INITIALIZED" in keras-based convolutional network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, cudnn

I'm trying to create a convolutional network using keras. However, I'm getting the following error:

> 2018-08-05 21:10:44.670676: E
>   T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:332]
>   could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED 2018-08-05
>   21:10:44.670843: E
>   T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\stream_executor\cuda\cuda_dnn.cc:336]
>   error retrieving driver version: Unimplemented: kernel reported driver
>   version not implemented on Windows

I haven't installed cudnn seperately, only installed tensorflow-gpu through pip (not using the url). A seperate program that doesn't use a convolutional network works fine. My code:

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow import keras
    from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
    import matplotlib.pylab as plt
    import numpy as np
    batch_size = 64
    num_classes = 10
    epochs = 10

    # input image dimensions
    img_x, img_y = 32, 32

    # Load cifar data from file
    # define standard sizing values
    image_height = 32
    image_width = 32
    color_channels = 3

    model_name = "cifar"


    def unpickle(file):
        import pickle
        with open(file, 'rb') as fo:
            dict = pickle.load(fo, encoding='bytes')
        return dict


    # Set the path as a mutable variable and initiate our training stuff
    cifar_path = 'cifar-10-batches-py/'

    x_train = np.array([])
    y_train = np.array([])

    # Load all the data batches.
    for i in range(1, 3):
        data_batch = unpickle(cifar_path + 'data_batch_' + str(i))
        x_train = np.append(x_train, data_batch[b'data'])
        y_train = np.append(y_train, data_batch[b'labels'])

    # Load the eval batch.
    eval_batch = unpickle(cifar_path + 'test_batch')

    x_test = eval_batch[b'data']
    y_test = eval_batch[b'labels']

    # Load the english category names.
    category_names_bytes = unpickle(cifar_path + 'batches.meta')[b'label_names']
    category_names = list(map(lambda x: x.decode("utf-8"), 
    category_names_bytes))


    def process_data(data):
        float_data = np.array(data, dtype=float) / 255.0

        reshaped_data = np.reshape(float_data, (-1, color_channels, image_height, image_width))

    # The incorrect image

        transposed_data = np.transpose(reshaped_data, [0, 2, 3, 1])
        return transposed_data


    # redefine the data with it in its processed form
    x_train = process_data(x_train)

    x_test = process_data(x_test)
    # reshape the data into a 4D tensor - (sample_number, x_img_size, y_img_size, num_channels)
    x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], img_x, img_y, 3)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], img_x, img_y, 3)
    input_shape = (img_x, img_y, 3)

    # convert the data to the right type
    x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
    x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
    x_train /= 255
    x_test /= 255
    print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
    print(x_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
    print(x_test.shape[0], 'test samples')

    # convert class vectors to binary class matrices - this is for use in the
    # categorical_crossentropy loss below
    y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
    y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1000, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])


    class AccuracyHistory(keras.callbacks.Callback):
        def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
            self.acc = []

        def on_epoch_end(self, batch, logs={}):
            self.acc.append(logs.get('acc'))

    history = AccuracyHistory()

    model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          callbacks=[history])
    score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)
    print('Test loss:', score[0])
    print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
    plt.plot(range(1, 11), history.acc)
    plt.xlabel('Epochs')
    plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include cudnn in your environment variables(if on windows), if you need to run tensorflow-gpu.